# My servlet-mapping is directly matched default servlet

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets, glassfish

I get some question today.

This below is my servlet-mapping contents of web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>static-resource</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>static-resource</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/statis-resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My application directory structure is:

```
/WEB-INF
/static-resource
```

I hope to this

1. This case of the request is mapping to `static-resource` servlet

   - `http://myserver/static-resource/test.js`
   - `http://myserver/static-resource/images/img1.jpg`
   - `http://myserver/static-resource/test.xml`
2. And this case of the request is mapping to `dispatcher` servlet

   - `http://myserver/other/whole/uri`

But, my web.xml is whole of the request mapping to `dispatcher` servlet directly.
Below is my glassfish server log on request

[#|2014-10-28T09:54:27.722+0900|WARNING|glassfish3.1|org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound|_ThreadID=680;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/static-resource/test.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'|#]

So, I wondered, why whole of requests are mapped to `dispatcher` servlet?
Anyone help me?

Update

---

Sorry my misstake, I correct misstype but still response 404 error.  Hmm... probably have another problems?

Comment: Because you typed `statis-resource` instead of `static-resource`?

Answer (score 1):

Servlet mapping is done on the basis of most specific URL matching. So you are using the right approach but just doing a typo mistake for word static in your URL here:

```
<url-pattern>/statis-resource/*</url-pattern>
```

change it to

```
<url-pattern>/static-resource/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Check this out. Maybe some problem exist http://the-double-0-project.blogspot.kr/2010/04/serving-static-resources-in-glassfish-3.html